# Magic Mouse scrolling on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, magic-mouse

I've managed to get the mouse detected and the general clicking and mouse moving functionality works fine, but no scrolling, nor gestures?

I'm unsure if gestures are supported, if not that's completely fine.

But does anyone know how to get the scrolling to work?

I assume if the functionality works on Windows 7 it'll also comply with Windows 8.  I haven't had any luck with what I've found on the net.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look into this utility. It will install the necessary utilities for touch scroll support. Have not verified that it works, but looks promising.

http://www.trackpadmagic.com/magic-mouse/download

Comment: They don't offer a perpetual license, you need to pay a yearly subscription. I understand that there isn't much demand, but $2 / month for using my own mouse and keyboard is a bit ridiculous

Answer (score 10):

I was searching for magic mouse drivers but unable to find it, So I applied my old technique and it worked!.

Just Download Boot Camp Support Software 5.0.5033 or latest from apple BootCamp download page 
[Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638)

- Unzip BootCamp5.0.5033.zip (use winrar, 7zip etc)
- Go to folder BootCamp->Drivers->Apple
- Simply install AppleWirelessMouse64.exe
- Restart and Done!

Tested on Asus zenbook with Windows 8 core and  Windows 8.1 Pro Preview...

Comment: Didn't even require a restart for me. Plus, the software download (although large) is directly from Apple, rather than trusting a 3rd party

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Drivers directly from Apple rather some some (unknown to me) third party.

Comment: Scroll with second version of the mouse is not working in Windows 8.1 yet. Drivers didn't helped.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 today, using the first version of the mouse (the one with 2 AA batteries).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Windows 8 is still new enough that Magic Mouse support (officially or unofficially) hasn't been added yet.  Given enough time, Windows 8 should support the Magic Mouse as well.

Not everything is forward compatible. Or backward compatible for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Apple do not support Windows 8 on Boot Camp yet, and made the Magic Mouse specifically to require drivers (It's not completely HID plug n play). They never released the internal specs of the MM nor did they release drivers anywhere else than with BootCamp so nobody else is going to make their own drivers anytime soon.

To put it simply, they don't want you to have one on Windows unless it's for your Mac and you're using BootCamp, and seeing as BootCamp does not support Win8 yet, you will have to wait until it does then rip the drivers from that.

Answer (score -1):

If you updated to Windows 8.1 you should have in mind that many users are experiencing mouse problems. You should try the [fix for mouse lag in this article](http://www.virusresearch.org/windows-8-1-mouse-lag/) or completely reinstalling Windows 8.1.

> Here is a short description of the steps:
>
> 1. Right-click the game's icon.
> 2. Select Properties.
> 3. Select the Compatibility tab.
> 4. Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows 7.
> 5. Check the box next to Disable display scaling on high DPI settings.
> 6. Click on OK.
>
> This should fix games that do not use DirectX
>   and the workaround for this mouse problem is to Disable display
>   scaling on high DPI settings.

Comment: this answer is totally irrelevant