# Disable Magic Mouse scrolling in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, scrolling, magic-mouse

I have a Windows 8.1 machine (Mac Mini, boot camp), and an Apple Magic Mouse.

Is there a way to disable both vertical and horizontal scrolling, or at least horizontal? The mouse seems to have a mind of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use regedit to go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` and set `WheelScrollChars` to zero.

Ensure that you have installed the right drivers from bootcamp
with procedures similar to those described in the following posts :

- [Install Apple’s Magic Mouse Drivers on Windows 8](http://www.shoutpedia.com/install-apples-magic-mouse-drivers-on-windows-8-with-natural-scrolling-and-battery-percentage/)
- [Magic Mouse scrolling on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/a/634389/8672)